# Reference in bibliography not formatted as expected

Tags: bibtex

I'm currently writing my thesis and there is a problem with `inBook` and my required citation style `unsrtdin`.

I expected the output to look like this:

[image]

but i get the following:

[image]

instead of type I want to get author (Urheber, Vorname) in small caps and insted of author (Urheber, Vorname) I want to get editor (Herausgeber, Vorname) in small caps. (ed.) or (Hrsg.) in german is also missing. I tried to swap the fields, but if use the field type for author, I don't get it in small caps and the interpunctation is wrong.

I tried to look into the source code of unsrtdin.bst, but this is beyond me...

Tanks in advance, ally healp would be much appreciated!

unsrtdin: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505

A minimal working example of my thesis is the following:

```
\documentclass{test}
\begin{document}
     bla \citep{Maher1996} bla.
    \bibliography{StudArb_bibliography_Kopie}
    \clearpage
\end{document}
```

with the bibtex file:

```
    @InBook{Maher1996,
  author       = {Urheber, Vorname},
  title        = {Titel des Sammelbandes},
  chapter      = {Titel},
  edition      = {Auflage},
  editor      = {Herausgeber, Vorname} ,
  isbn         = {978-3540624677},
  pages        = {Anfangsseite-Schlusseite},
  publisher    = {Verlag},
  address       = {Ort},
  year         = {Erscheinungsjahr},
 type = {type},
}
```

and using the test.cls file:

```
\ProvidesClass{StudArb}[2016/12/07 KTmfk StudArb LaTeX class]
\LoadClass[%
    a4paper,
    12pt,
    parskip=half+,
    %parindent=0.0pt,
    twoside,
    open=any,
    captions=tableheading,
    index=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}
\RequirePackage{etex}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[babel]{microtype}
\RequirePackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\RequirePackage{yfonts}
\RequirePackage{pifont}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{marvosym}
\RequirePackage[svgnames,table,hyperref,table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[tbtags]{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage{bbm}
\RequirePackage{blkarray}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{leading}
\RequirePackage[%
    a4paper,%
    top=27.5mm,%
    right=22.5mm,%
    bottom=25.0mm,%
    left=30.0mm,%
    ignoreheadfoot,%
]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}  %% Seitennummer
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}  %% Kapitelname
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.05em}  %% Trennlinie (Kopfzeile)
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0em} %% Trennlinie (Fußzeile)
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\thechapter~#1}{}%
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{subfig}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{placeins}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{ltcaption}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{hhline}
\RequirePackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\RequirePackage[%
    pdfstartpage=1,
    pdfstartview=FitV,
    pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=NavyBlue,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    plainpages=false,
    hypertexnames=false,
]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{listings}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of mistakes in the entry in question:

- Incorrect entry type: You should be using `@incollection`, not `@inbook`.
- Incorrect use of fields: You should replace

  ```
  title        = {Titel des Sammelbandes},
  chapter      = {Titel},
  ```

  with

  ```
  booktitle    = {Titel des Sammelbandes},
  title        = {Titel},
  ```

  If you wish to supply the chapter *number* (not title), you could further write

  ```
  chapter      = {5},
  ```

  or whatever the chapter number may be.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@incollection{Maher1996,
  author       = {Urheber, Vorname},
  booktitle    = {Titel des Sammelbandes},
  title        = {Titel},
  edition      = {Auflage},
  editor       = {Herausgeber, Vorname} ,
  isbn         = {978-3540624677},
  pages        = {Anfangsseite--Schlusseite},
  publisher    = {Verlag},
  address      = {Ort},
  year         = {Erscheinungsjahr},
  type         = {type},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem completely.